# Different implementation for different enum value

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a question which is more design related. I am writing validators for my classes and I want a different vlidator for lets say save logic than update logic. So I was creating an interface which should be something like 
interface **IObjectValidator>ObjectToValidate, ValidationForMethod<** and not sure what I can do to use to do something like **UserValidatorForSave : IObjectValidator>User, ValidationMethod.Save<**
I know it's not making much sense but kindly suggest a solution where I can do something like that.

Comment: "I know it's not making much sense" - then think more about your question until it does make sense.

Comment: `I know it's not making much sense`, can't really suggest something.

Comment: Generally you'd use `ISaveObjectValidator : IObjectValidator ` and `IUpdateObjectValidator : IObjectValidator` for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking to do something like that too. But just thought maybe there is a better solution. But thanks

Comment: If you find your self using an enum always think twice if you actually need that sort of branching and whether this should be an implementation. Although enums are extremely useful, they shouldnt really be used for switches and branching like this, when you could seperate the concern entirely

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
class ValidatorInitializer
{
    public IObjectValidator Initialize(MyEnumType myEnum)
    {
        IObjectValidator validator = null;
        switch (myEnum)
        { 
            case MyEnumType.Case1 :
                validator = new UserValidatorForSave() ;
                break;
            case MyEnumType.Case2 :
                validator = new UserValidatorForUpdate();
                break;
        }

        return validator;
    }
}
```

then just use it in this way

```
var validator = (new ValidatorInitializer()).Initialize(myEnum);
```

With dependency injection

```
services.AddScoped<IObjectValidator>(provider =>
{
   var enumResolverService = provider.GetRequiredService<IEnumResolverService>();
   return (new ValidatorInitializer()).Initialize(enumResolverService.MyEnum));
}
```

you need an `IEnumResolverService` which will provide information to your factory method so that your factory method will know what to resolve.

Comment: Yeah factory is also a good option, but I was trying to use Dependency injection

Comment: you can use dependency injection with factory approach in .net core. Please check my edit

Comment: I posted an example for you.